# android application arabic support

Tags: android, arabic

i have followed tutorial Hello L10 in developer.android official website,but nothing regarding arabic.

**what are the steps needed for an android application to be in arabic?**
for eg,User can have either a combobox or radio button to choose from english or arabic.(i have done this).

Now if user selects arabic whole application characters should be converted in arabic.
**even the keyboard presented should be in arabic**?if i have to make custom keyboard for this?or any other way?
i dont have any idea.Any tutorial/demo ?.However i have googled around but not get specific material.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Follow this helpful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813) and enjoy! There is a complete description of problem and an algorithm as its solution.

Comment: Take a look on this answer it may help 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16854772/2267723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users set their locale at the device level, through the Settings application. If their device supports Arabic -- some devices running Android 2.3 and 3.0 will -- then if your application has Arabic translations of its resources, the Arabic will appear. Also, the user will get an Arabic soft keyboard.

Other than providing Arabic translations for your strings, the rest is up to the user and their device.